# lambda s3 trigger event No such file or directory error

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda

When an image is uploaded to s3, we try to load the image into the lambda function. The CloudWatch log contains the error 'Cam20210327_201656946.jpg'. Which code should I modify?
Triggered s3 bucket on lambda.

```
import urllib.parse
import boto3
import uuid
import os
import io
import json
import csv
ENDPOINT_NAME = 'T4'
# grab environment variables
ENDPOINT_NAME = os.environ['ENDPOINT_NAME']
runtime= boto3.client('runtime.sagemaker')
s3_client = boto3.client('s3')

def handler(event, context):
 try:
  for record in event['Records']:
         
   bucket = record['s3']['bucket']['name']
        
   key = record['s3']['object']['key']
   download_path = '/tmp/{}'.format(key)
   payload = None
  with open(download_path, 'rb') as f:
   payload = f.read()
   payload = bytearray(payload)
  
   response = runtime.invoke_endpoint(EndpointName=ENDPOINT_NAME,ContentType='application/x-image',
                                   Body=payload)
                                   
   result = json.loads(response['Body'].read().decode())
   print(result)
   index = np.argmax(result)
   image_categories = ['glass', 'plastic bag', 'food', 'metal', 'styrofoam', 'paper','plastic', 'clothing']
   print("Result: label - " + image_categories[index] + ", probability - " + str(result[index]))
   return image_categories[index]
  except Exception as e:
   print(e)
```

Comment: On which line is it throwing this error and what is the exact error statement?

Comment: with open(download_path, 'rb') as f:
An error occurs here.
An error occurs that the jpg file does not exist in the specified path.

Comment: This is the error message. [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/Cam20210327_201642276.jpg'

Comment: I don't see any s3 download command in your code. Did you miss the line to download the jpg file to tmp folder?

Comment: s3_client.download_file(bucket,key,'/tmp/{}'.format(key)) I solved it using this code. Thank you.